# Segmentation fault in (Bag Of Words)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement bag of words in OpenCV. Basically for now JUST for  testing, I have used only 4 images (which you will see in my code below). everything seems to be cool and smooth but when I reach to

`BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowide(&extractor, &matcher);`

my compile is successful but when I run the test I got `Segmentation Fault`, which I think, it might be the problem in inserting the images or something else..

Any advice?

Comment: Advice? Did you try a debugger, or at least printing messages to narrow down where the problem seems to occur?

Comment: Yeah, I told you up, when I reach to this BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowide(&extractor, &matcher); I got the problem, before that everything is working well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs for `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_object_categorization.html#bowimgdescriptorextractor) it looks like `extractor` and `matcher` should be held in [`Ptr`s](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html?highlight=ptr#ptr), something like (untested):

```
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor(new SurfDescriptorExtractor);
...
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> >);
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowide(extractor, matcher);
```